# Angular - CSS se rompe cuando utiliza animaciones

Tags: angular

He creado una animación de fadeout para navegar entre páginas. Aparentemente todo funciona pero ocurre un extraño error. Cuando carga la página y empieza la animación el CSS se "rompe" y agrega un espacio en blanco a la derecha, quedando algo así.

[image: Error]

Cuando termina la animación vuelve a su estado normal. En la imagen hay una página de login que ocupa toda la pantalla.

La animación es así

```
import {
  trigger,
  animate,
  transition,
  style,
  query,
} from "@angular/animations";

export const fadeAnimation = trigger("fadeAnimation", [
    transition('* => *', [
        query(':enter', [style({ position:'fixed',opacity: 0 }) ], { optional: true }),
        query(':leave', [ animate('3s ease-in-out', style({position:'fixed', opacity: 0 })) ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [ animate('3s ease-in-out', style({position:'fixed', opacity: 1 })) ], { optional: true })
    ])
]);
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ocurrir esto?

Comment: Sería bueno que colocaras el código en una IDE Online como stackblitz para poder depurar mejor tu problema.